# Variable size LRU cache

Tags: java, caching, hashtable, lru

I am trying to implement an `LRU cache` in Java which should be able to:
Change size dynamically. In the sense that I plan to have it as `SoftReference` subscribed to a `ReferenceQueue`. So depending upon the memory consumption, the cache size will vary.

I plan to use `ConcurrentHashMap` where the value will be a soft reference and then periodically clear the queue to update the map.
But the problem with the above is that, how do I make it `LRU`?

I know that we have no control over GC, but can we manage references to the value (in cache) in such a manner that all the possible objects in cache, will become softly reachable (under GC) depending upon usage (i.e. the last time it was accessed) and not in some random manner.

Comment: Guava's [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) should work well here, which mixes in LRU features derived from [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](http://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap).

Answer (score 4):

Neither weak nor soft references are really well suited for this. WeakReferences tend to get cleared immediatly as soon as the object has no stronger references anymore and soft references get cleared only after the heap has grown to it's maximum size and when a OutOufMemoryError would need to be thrown otherwise.

Typically it's more efficient to use some time based approach with regular strong refernces which are much cheaper for the VM than the Reference subclasses (faster to handle for the program and the GC and use no extra memory for the reference itself.). I.e. release all objects that have not been used for a certain time. You can check this with a periodic TimerTask that you would need anyway to operate your reference queue. The idea is that if it takes i.e. 10ms to create the object and you keep it at most 1s after it was last used you will on average only be 1% slower than when you would keep all objects forever. But since it will most likely use less memory it will actually be faster.

*Edit:* One way to implement this would be to use 3 buckets internally. Objects that are placed into the cache get always inserted into bucket 0. When a object is requested the cache looks for it in all 3 buckets in order and places it into bucket 0 if it was not already there. The TimerTask gets invoked in fixed intervals and just drops bucket 2 and places a new empty bucket at the front of the bucket list, so that the new bucket 0 will be empty and the former bucket 0 becomes 1 and the former bucket 1 is now bucket 2. This will ensure that idle objects will survive at least one and at most two timer intervals and that objects that are accessed more than once per interval are very fast to retrieve. The total maintenance overhead for such a data structure will be considerably smaller than everything that is based on reference objects and reference queues.

Comment: I agree to the statement that: Same time complexity will be used for TimerTask or Reference thread as both will have to iterate over same elements. And also with not playing much around with memory, it will be more predictable and reliable. But what about size? Also Neo4J uses the same mechanism (https://github.com/neo4j/community/blob/master/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/cache/WeakLruCache.java) and they seem quite happy and proud about it. Probably profiling of all the above different techniques should make it better. But overall I still think Map with SoftRef should be best.

Comment: If you want to limit the total number of cached objects with the implementation I suggested above, you could simply trigger the bucket rotation when you reached your total size limit after the insertion of a new object and leave a flag set for the timer job to let it know not to do anything this time (timer resets the flag). This would make your cache switch from time based mode to size limited mode (and back) automatically. You should also initiate a rotation if bucket 0 becomes i.e. half the total max size to maintain the LRU characteristic of the cache and improve it's worst case behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't really make sense unless you want several of these caches at the same time. If you have only a single cache, don't give it a size limit and always use `WeakReference`. That way, the cache will automatically use all available free memory.

Prepare for some hot discussions with your sysadmins, though, since they will come complaining that your app has a memory leak and "will crash any moment!" *sigh*

The other option is to use a mature cache library like [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/) since it already knows everything that there is to know about caches and they spent years getting them right - literally. Unless you want to spend years debugging your code to make it work with every corner case of the Java memory model, I suggest that you avoid reinventing the wheel this time.

Comment: I think I did not convey it properly. I do not want to switch between weak and soft. What I desire is a cache with soft references (so that it can scale accordingly) which acts as a lru cache.

Comment: Ah. Then you will have to use `LinkedHashMap` or write your own map. No other map in Java can be limited in size. Guava, for example, uses their own `CacheBuilder` to build caches with certain limits since nothing on the Java runtime offers enough control.

Comment: So basically LinkedHashMap with some extra effort along to decide the size is the best approach considerably?

Comment: It's the approach that takes the least effort but still returns something useful + LRU. If you can live without LRU, `WeakHashMap` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry%28java.util.Map.Entry%29) as it support access order and use as a LRU map. It can have a variable maximum size.

Switching between weak and soft references based on usage is very difficult to get right because.  Its hard to determine a) how much your cache is using exclusively, b) how much is being used by the system c) how much would be used after a Full GC.

You should note that weak and soft references are only cleaned on a GC, and that discarding them or changing them won't free memory until a GC is run.

Comment: The problem is: I will have to manually change the size depending upon the total memory if LinkedHashMap. And for the last statement, I do not understand why that should be an issue.

Comment: Its only an issue if you expect it to make a difference. IMHO I wouldn't add complexity which won't help.  There is no way to know the total memory used without performing a full GC and then there is no way to force entries removed to be freed up without another GC.

Comment: I think I did not convey it properly. I do not want to switch between weak and soft. What I desire is a cache with soft references (so that it can scale accordingly) which acts as a lru cache.

Comment: Can you use a `LinkedHashMap<Key, SoftReference<Value>>` ?

Comment: No. It still wont make it LRU. But yes it will indeed make the objects last longer due to the restricted size of the map (hence lru for a particular period but not forever). But again what needs to be the size of the map will remain a bigger issue.   PS: I have edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: LHM supports LRU by setting it to be access order instead of insertion order.